# How to search for multi work tags with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

I have three tables

```
Tags    | tag_id,tag_name
Tag_link| tag_id,item_id
Item    | item_id
```

An Item can have more than one tag, and these tags can be multiple words

I tried splitting the input into different words

```
SELECT * FROM Item i
join Tag_link l on l.item_id=l.item_id
join Tags     t on t.tag_id =l.tag_id
WHERE REGEXP 'test|query|yay'
```

But I want in this search an item with a tag of `test query yay` to be ranked higher than if it had just `test` or `query` but I also want  `test query` and `query yay` to be searched for too.

Will I just have to do this in my PHP and split it into all the different combinations and what to look for, assigning a number to each query and then sort on that?

Comment: Are the number of words limited or is it up to the user? Two options to have multiple joins if the number is fixed or multiple queries if not.

Comment: Realistically I would probably limit the number of characters in a query.

Comment: Why don't you use *fulltext* in this scenario? [read here] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)